# How to dress professionally at high temperatures?

Tags: dress-code, temperature

In summer, temperatures in your office might be very high. Do you have any hints for clothes that are both professional and comfortable in this situation?

(See also [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30593/how-to-dress-professionally-in-a-chilly-workplace) for the case of low temperatures.)

Comment: For instance, I do not mind to wear shorts and a t-shirt while attending lectures or doing research at a university, but I guess I would never wear this outfit when working in a company.

Comment: I agree that "appropriate" is going to vary from workplace to workplace. General rule - follow the lead of your coworkers.

Comment: This is going to vary from industry to industry and office to office.

Comment: I think this is *at least* salvageable with an edit if not fine as is. We have a [handful of well-scoring, open questions about dressing in the workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=business%20casual%20is%3aquestion) - including the reciprocal question that OP linked. If the question was narrowed down to *business casual* or *business attire* I can't see how it would vary from office to office. Side note: what happens if you are interviewing and can't sample the office's culture/ lead of your coworkers prior to the interview?

Comment: Bermuda shorts?

Comment: Why is this marked as off topic?

Comment: I usually go with this http://www.buzzle.com/images/fashion/casual-business-wear/dusky-blue-shirt-blue-jeans-casual-businesswear-for-men.jpg

Answer (score 5):

In the Philippines, a tropical country, you can dress professionally (smart casual/business) with the following examples:

Men:

- Lightly-colored polo with cuffs
- No tie
- Light grey, brown, or any conservatively-colored pants
- Leather shoes of any conservative color
- Polo shirt, a piece of clothing whose collar and fabric is the same as a polo, but the arms and length from nape to the waist are as short as that of a shirt. You can fan your back from below with this one.

Women:

- Sleeved polo shirts, with a 1/4 to 3/4 cut on the sleeves.
- Skirts that are at least two inches below the knee
- Non-denim pants of conservative colors.
- Black or flesh-colored stockings.
- Flats or heels with conservative patterns or plainly colored in any color.

In smart casual and business attire, shoes are very important. They need to be closed. Toes must not be seen. Baring legs are generally viewed as unprofessional, especially if they are hairy.

Comment: That's highly dependent on the country. In brazil, unless you are working at a bank, you will have a hard time finding any woman with closed shoes. Same for the legs!